# $f$ bounded over $[a,\infty )$, $f'(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=b$, then $b=0$.

Tags: limits, continuity

$f$ bounded over $[a,\infty )$, $f'(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=b$, then $b=0$.

WLOG, let $a=\max_x f(x)$
$f$ bounded over $[a,\infty)$
$$\implies \exists M>0 \text{ s.t. }|f(x)|\le M=f(a)\space\space\forall\space\space x\in [a,\infty)$$

By MVT, $\exists x\in [a,x+a)$ s.t.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)=\lim \frac{f(x+a)-f(a)}{x}=\lim\frac{f(x+a)-M}{x}\le \lim\frac{M-M}{x}=0$$

How do I show that $\lim f'(x)>=0$?

Answer (score 1):

For every $x \geq a$ and some $c(x)\in (x,2x)$ there results $$f(2x)-f(x)=f'(c(x))x.$$ Hence $$f'(c(x)) = \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}.$$ By assumption, and since $c(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$, the left-hand side tends to $b$. The numerator of the right-hand size is bounded by $2M$, while the denominator diverges. Hence $b=0$.

Your approach is essentially correct, but you do not want to get the strongest conclusion: when you deal with a fraction $p(x)/q(x)$ in which the numerator remains bounded and the denominator diverges, the fraction tends to zero. You should not be satisfied by a one-sided comparison.

Comment: how did you get $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c(x))x$? By MVT, it would be $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c(x))$. thank you

Comment: Try $f(2x) - f(x)$ then

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. I have inserted @John's suggestion.